# cutoff error using custom kernel in Smooth.ppp

Tags: spatstat

I need to use a custom kernel with the Smooth function, but attempting this throws an error even though I specify cutoff:

Error: The argument ‘cutoff’ is required when a non-Gaussian kernel is specified and scalekernel=FALSE

```
n=4; PPP=ppp(rep(1:n,n),rep(1:n,each=n), c(1,n),c(1,n), marks=1:n^2);
Smooth.ppp(PPP,cutoff=50,kernel=gaussian,at="points")
```

Here is a toy example that makes the same error. I'm not 100% sure whether this is an error or something that's unintuitive to me. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug. Thank you for bringing it to our attention.

It has been fixed in the development version of `spatstat.core` (`2.4-2.003`) which is available at the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/spatstat/spatstat.core)

The bug only affects the case where `kernel` is a function, `at="points"`, and `scalekernel=FALSE`.  In the meantime you can get the desired result by either

1. Adding `scalekernel=TRUE` and `sigma=1`, or
2. Deleting `at="points"` so that the result is a pixel image `Z` say, and extracting the desired values by `Z[PPP]`.